# awk for motif splicing from an amino acid alignment

Tags: perl, awk

I'm looking to splice out specific amino acid alignment positions as a continuous motif from an alignment (~15 000 sequences). The code is written in Perl (I agree not many developers now) but splicing method is awk which a lot of you know. Please note the hash is "tied" (not shown), this just means the order of the sequences is preserved.  I can get the awk code below to return single amino acid positions.

I am struggling to get a loop working in awk.

I agree the Perl wrapper makes it more complicated, but its part of a huge data pipeline (all written in Perl).

```perl
#!/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.20/bin/env perl
#use strict;
use warnings;

# I loaded the alignment into a hash, where key = sequence and value = protein
my %dna = (
    virus1 => "LGVLVILLMVQEGLKKRMTTKIIISTSMAVLVAMILGGFSMSDLAKLAILMGATFAEMNTGGDVAHLALIAAFKVRPALLVSFIF", 
    virus2 => "LGVLVILLMVQEGLKKRMTTKIIISTSMAVLVAMILGGFSMSDLAKLAILMGATFAEMNTGGDVXXXXXXAAFKVRPALLVSFIF", 
    virus3 => "LGVLVILLMVQEGLKKRMTTKIIISTSMAVLVAMILGGFSMSDLAKLAILMGATFAEMNTGGZZZZZZLIAAFKVRPALLVSFIF"
);

# I define the start and end of the alignment positions I am splicing
my $n = 1;
my $z = 5;

# I turn the alignment into a string with separated by carriage returns 
my @array = map {"$dna{$_}"} keys %dna;
my $string = join "\n", @array;

# This is the awk loop, note in Perl the "``" means issue a shell command 

my $splice = `echo "$string" | awk 'BEGIN {FS=""} {x = $n; while (x < $z); print \$ x; ++x}' 2>1`;
print $splice;
__DATA__
```

**Expected output**

```
LGVLV
LGVLV
LGVLV
```

**Observed output**
I get the original sequences returned

I am familiar with Python/Perl solutions of line by line processing but awk is more efficient IMO.

Comment: Could you [edit] and show the output you're expecting? I speak both Perl and awk, but I don't get what output you want. Also, I really doubt that calling awk will be more efficient than doing it natively in perl. You don't seem to be using anything that awk is particularly good at.

Comment: Amended, thanks. I will post the solution I got working, but this is because I don't understand awk

Comment: The main problem is that your `while` only encloses the first statement after it, and not the second. You need `{ }` for that. If you could explain what that awk is supposed to be doing (I'm pretty sure you've copied it wrong, is there really a space between `\$` and `x`?), I should be able to post an answer. Do you just want the first 5 characters of each sequence? Don't you want positions `$n` to `$z` (3-7)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you are trying to use `awk` to get characters 3 through 7 (inclusive) of each input sequence. If so, a working version of your approach would be this:

```
my $splice = `echo "$string" | awk 'BEGIN {FS=\"\"} {x = $n; while (x < $z){ printf \"%s\",\$x; ++x} print ""}' 2>1`;
```

That, when added to your perl script, produces:

```
$ foo.pl
VLVIL
VLVIL
VLVIL
```

That isn't the output you show, but the output you show is just the first 5 letters of each sequence, which doesn't seem to correspond to what your script is doing.

Now, the reason your version didn't work, is that the `while` was like so:

```
while (x < $z); print \$ x; ++x}
```

Assuming the `\$ x` was a typo, the problem is that the `++x` isn't part of the while loop. So that should never even have exited. Seeing as we're in the same time zone, and given the time, I am guessing you're tired and that you miscopied something when trying to give us a reproducible example. In any case, to get the loop right, you need `{}`:

```
while (x < $z){print \$x; ++x}
```

However, if all you want is a substring, a loop is a very inefficient way of doing that. You can instead use `awk`'s `substr` command:

```
  substr(s, m[, n ])
             Return  the at most n-character substring of s that begins at position
             m, numbering from 1. If n is omitted, or if n specifies  more  charac‐
             ters than are left in the string, the length of the substring shall be
             limited by the length of the string s.
```

So, in your script, that would be:

```
my $splice = `echo "$string" | awk '{print substr(\$0,$n,5)}'
```

---

Since you're already using a language that excels in string manipulation, I really don't understand why you would try to use `awk` instead. It will not be faster or more efficient than the same thing in perl:

```
print substr($_,$n,5) . "\n" for @array;
```

By calling `awk` you are also calling the shell which will be slower by definition, especially if you're `echo`ing thousands of lines. In fact, I tried this with 15000 sequences (just repetitions of your first one) and using either the `awk` loop I gave above, or the `awk`+`substr`, or the native perl `substr`:

1. awk loop, average time taken to run the same thing 100 times: 0.0525
2. awk substr, average time taken to run the same thing 100 times: 0.0522s
3. perl substr, average time taken to run the same thing 100 times: 0.0464

And you can make it even faster by skipping the array and iterating over the keys directly:

```
print substr($dna{$_},$n,5) . "\n" for keys(%dna);
```

That averaged at 0.0376s over 100 runs.

Comment: Huge thanks @terdon. You are right I should have performed a runtime check :-( such as use Timer::Runtime. I worked on the implicit assumption awk was faster for this operation. David Cross "lectured" on runtime in detail in "Data Munging for Perl": There is no denying that 0.0525 vs. 0.0376s is 30% faster.

Comment: @MichaelG. in my experience, awk is blindingly fast when your data are organized in fields because of its implicit splitting. If not, however, it doesn't give any real advantage over a language like Perl which is simply brilliant for text parsing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the sequences in a seperate file like this:

```
$ cat input
LGVLVILLMVQEGLKKRMTTKIIISTSMAVLVAMILGGFSMSDLAKLAILMGATFAEMNTGGDVAHLALIAAFKVRPALLVSFIF
LGVLVILLMVQEGLKKRMTTKIIISTSMAVLVAMILGGFSMSDLAKLAILMGATFAEMNTGGDVXXXXXXAAFKVRPALLVSFIF
LGVLVILLMVQEGLKKRMTTKIIISTSMAVLVAMILGGFSMSDLAKLAILMGATFAEMNTGGZZZZZZLIAAFKVRPALLVSFIF
```

you can use a simple `cut` to fetch a substring:

```
$ cut -c1-5 input
LGVLV
LGVLV
LGVLV
```